# Appropriates names for Api implementation and Api Client Library

Tags: .net, rest, api, naming, project-structure

Suppose I have a big project, called Northwind. It's a website in front of a database. Now management want me to create a public API for this.

I create a new ASP.NET Core project called `Northwind.Api`

But now the customers want a nuget package to invoke the API with. (They don't want to invoke REST calls directly). I would naturally call this client package `Northwind.Api`.

So there's a problem. Is there a convention for naming:

- The project that implements an API
- A library providing a wrapper that calls the API.

I can't call them both `Northwind.Api`.

Comment: I disagree with the close suggestion "Primarily Opinion Based". I am hoping to get an answer based on existing conventions.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can call Nuget project `Northwind.SDK`, it is not the API, yet it is some package that allows you develop software that uses the API with ease, one would say it is a software development kit. In fact, it is *the official* software development kit.

Another option for you is to call it `Northwind.ApiClient`, because it is a library that consumes the API. Although, it is only one client, not *the* client. I would prefer `Northwind.SDK`, unless you are already using that name for something else.

For a third option. You could call your ASP.NET Core project `Northwind.WebApi`. I suppose beyond the organization nobody is aware of that name. That would free the name `Northwind.Api`. Although I recognize that it could be too late to rename that project.

Comment: Thanks - I still haven't checked in the initial API project, so the appropriate time for me to rename it is now :-)